# Missing required prop: "id" at <AddProduct> - Laravel / Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

i want to pass a value from laravel blade to a Vue Component:

my Laravel blade:

```
<div id="add_product">
   <add-product :id="{{$product_id}}"></add-product>
</div>
```

my vue component:

```
export default {
    props:{
        id:{
            required : true
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.id)
    },
}
```

the problem is that i get this error :

> Missing required prop: "id" at AddProduct

it took me 4hours trying to find out the problem, hope you can help.

The Repo:
https://github.com/SimodevStuff/shopify-add-product-clone

Edited:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try

```html
<div id="add_product">
   <add-product id="{{$product_id}}"></add-product>
</div>
```

`id` without `:`.

in Vue prop prefixed with `:` is a shorthand for v-bind. Meaning, you are binding a property to the component. But you need to pass a value.

Comment: i did try it but nothing changed. 

Comment: @Forbidenn can you post rendered HTML? (just above part)

Comment: `@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div id="add_product">
            <add-product id="{{$product_id}}"></add-product>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection`

Comment: @Forbidenn rendered in browser

Comment: i edited the post with a screenshot of it .

Comment: can u please help find the problem on the repo. https://github.com/SimodevStuff/shopify-add-product-clone